# ActiveMQ: No suitable Log constructor

Tags: java, macos, activemq-classic

I'm trying to run ActiveMQ on Mac OSX 10.5.7. I have Java version 1.5.0_19 and ActiveMQ 5.2.0. Below is the exception I get when running `bin/activemq`. It seems to be unable to find Log4j which is odd considering it comes with ActiveMQ and is definitely in the `lib/optional` directory. The only thing I can think of is that I have a conflict somewhere, but I can't imagine how this is possible. If anyone has any tips whatsoever I'm all ears. Googling produced almost no results with the same error, and the one person who has the exact error doesn't have a solution.

```
brad-robertsons-macbook-pro:apache-activemq-5.2.0
bradrobertson$ ./bin/activemq
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /Users/bradrobertson/Java/apache-activemq-5.2.0
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /Users/bradrobertson/Java/apache-activemq-5.2.0
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: java.io.IOException: Could not load xbean factory:java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: java.io.IOException: Could not load xbean factory:java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:98)
  at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
  at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:129)
  at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
  at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:79)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
  at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:225)
  at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not load xbean factory:java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:27)
  at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBrokerFactoryHandler(BrokerFactory.java:43)
  at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:70)
  at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
  at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.startBroker(StartCommand.java:115)
  at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:74)
  ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:494)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:350)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)
  at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:55)
  at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:42)
  at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBrokerFactoryHandler(BrokerFactory.java:41)
  ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: No suitable Log constructor [Ljava.lang.Class;@abcc03 for org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger (Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/log4j/Category) (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: No suitable Log constructor [Ljava.lang.Class;@abcc03 for org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger (Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Category))
  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:543)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
  at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.<clinit(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:43)
  ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: No suitable Log constructor [Ljava.lang.Class;@abcc03 for org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger (Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Category)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:413)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
  ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Category
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2357)
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2671)
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1629)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:410)
  ... 28 more
ERROR: java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Could not load xbean factory:java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Could not load xbean factory:java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:99)
  at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
  at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:129)
  at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
  at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:79)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
  at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:225)
  at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not load xbean factory:java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:27)
  at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBrokerFactoryHandler(BrokerFactory.java:43)
  at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:70)
  at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
  at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.startBroker(StartCommand.java:115)
  at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:74)
  ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:494)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:350)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)
  at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:55)
  at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:42)
  at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBrokerFactoryHandler(BrokerFactory.java:41)
  ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: No suitable Log constructor [Ljava.lang.Class;@abcc03 for org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger (Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Category) (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: No suitable Log constructor [Ljava.lang.Class;@abcc03 for org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger (Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Category))
  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:543)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
  at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.<clinit(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:43)
  ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: No suitable Log constructor [Ljava.lang.Class;@abcc03 for org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger (Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Category)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:413)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
  ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Category
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2357)
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2671)
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1629)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:410)
  ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it was definitely a conflict with another log4j jar file.  I think it's probably my eclipse plugin log4j that was conflicting.  When i delete the log4j from activemq lib/optional it works.

Comment: Is there a clear way of finding out if it is a conflict or a missing jar case?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the exception is being caused by a `NoClassDefFoundError` for `org.apache.log4j.Category`.  You should make sure that the `log4j` jar is on the classpath.

**Edit:** Is there any way that you can inspect the value of the `ACTIVEMQ_CLASSPATH` variable?  If you're invoking this through a script that is setting the variable, you might need to dig into the script to make sure it's adding all the directories you think it is to the classpath.

Comment: ya i can see that it doesn't recognize log4j.  I don't understand that though because log4j is within the lib/optional directory in the activemq dir.  And activemq is setting it's own ACTIVEMQ_CLASSPATH variable.  What's the point of including it in the download if it doesn't load it?  Or, could there be some conflict on my machine?  I don't know how I even check to see what jar it's getting. or if it's getting one at all