# JBPM installation on JBoss throws NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Category

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

When installing the JBPM with the full installer ( [guide here](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMInstaller.html) ) it breaks with the message `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Category`

I am working with jboss-5.1.0.GA and jbpm-4.4 - I have downloaded and followed the indications from [its official site](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMInstaller.html).
After prompting the starting of jBoss (`start.jboss`) and the installation of the sample project (`install.examples.into.jboss`) the script fails with the above exception followed by the similar Error (`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`).
The cmd I am using to launch the build is `ant demo.setup.jboss`.

I have also echoed the classpath of the `jbpm-deploy` command from ${jbpm.home}/examples/build.xml file and the log4j file, which contains the `org.apache.log4j.Category` class is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, the issue I had was caused by the same root problem as the one from [activemq No suitable Log constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059180/activemq-no-suitable-log-constructor) - I mean, conflicting jars.

I have removed the log4j.jar file from ${jbpm.home}/lib folder and the issue did not occur anymore.